# Joining Tables in MySQL with different where conditions on the same field?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following tables :

```
account => ID, Login, Pass, Email, Level, IDNum, Name
records => RID, Status, IDNum, Reason, Type, Amount, Date, SubmitterID
```

Now I join the tables with the following query:

```
SELECT account.Name FROM account, records WHERE records.IDNum = account.IDNum
```

In the query above the Name field would be joined based on matching IDNum, however if I want to get the Name field `WHERE account.ID = records.ID` and also `WHERE records.IDNum = account.IDNum` simultaneously, would that be possible?

Question in short, joining the 2 queries below into one :

```
SELECT account.Name FROM account, records WHERE records.IDNum = account.IDNum
SELECT account.Name FROM account, records WHERE records.SubmitterID = account.ID
```

I'm probably not clear enough, please check the example data below :

[image]

So obviously the `Name` field of the first query would return John, and return Chris for the second query. I want to display **both** names in one query.

Comment: What MySQL-version do you have, my 5.0 is just staring unbelieving at me if I try such a 'join'.

Comment: @Bobby : Sorry, corrected my query. I have MySQL 5.0.91.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually joinging EVERY rows and then filter out to retains only the one you want. You should instead filter them out right with the join:

```
select account.Name
FROM account
    INNER JOIN records ON (records.IDNum = account.IDNum AND records.SubmitterID = account.ID)
```

**EDIT: by OP question edit**

Seems you need and `OR` instead of `AND` in the above `JOIN`. Thus:

```
select account.Name
FROM account
    INNER JOIN records ON (records.IDNum = account.IDNum OR records.SubmitterID = account.ID)
```

**EDIT 2: follow-up to comment by OP**

```
create table account (id int, IDNum int, Name char(5));
insert into account values (1, 12345, 'John'), (2, NULL, 'Chris');
create table records (RID int, IDNum int, SubmitterID int);
insert into records values (1, 12345, 2);
select account.Name
FROM account
    INNER JOIN records ON (records.IDNum = account.IDNum OR records.SubmitterID = account.ID);
```

yields (with MySQL 5.1.46):

```
+-------+
| Name  |
+-------+
| John  |
| Chris |
+-------+
```

**EDIT 3: By OP second comment:**

Something like this?

```
select account.Name as byIDNum, NULL bySubmitterID
from account
    inner join records USING (IDNum)
union
select NULL, account.Name
from account
    inner join records ON (records.SubmitterID = account.ID);
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However this would only return one (single) value for the Name field whether `records.IDNum = account.IDNum` or `records.SubmitterID = account.ID`. I need to use both Name fields at the same time. Does this seem really strange?

Comment: @user435216: Sorry, I don't get the same results with my version of MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciated your help. Could the results for the first and second filters be saved into 2 different columns? Like creating some sort of alias. And I'm really sorry for my poor English, couldn't explain my question clearly in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood but wouldn't a simple AND accomplish what you need?

```
SELECT account.name
FROM account, records
WHERE records.IDNum = account.IDNum
AND records.SubmitterID = account.id
```

Or if you wanted to get return where either of these rules are true:

```
SELECT account.name
FROM account, records
WHERE records.IDNum = account.IDNum
OR records.SubmitterID = account.id
```

Comment: Extremely sorry for not being clear enough on my question, please check my updated question. Thanks.